# Why does Jess continue to go on voyages with her friends?

Tags: time-travel, triangle

From Jess's previous experience, she already knows that she is stuck in a time loop.

In the film [Triangle (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_(2009_British_film)), the last scene shows that Jess is at the yacht dock, and it seems like she is going on another voyage with her friends.

Why is she going on a second voyage when she already knows she will face another repetition of the same incidents?

Comment: Nope, not a second voyage, the *same* voyage, it's a time loop after all.

Comment: The fact that her dead friends are showing up to go with her should re-inforce Paulie_D's comment.

Comment: I've not seen the movie - so only leaving a comment for @Paulie_D and BCdotWEB.  Is the question not asking "why is she compelled to continue the voyage when she knows she is in a time loop" ? If she is at the dock, and is aware of what might happen, why does she not back out?